# access google cloud storage using java library gets '403 forbidden'

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

I'm trying to use google cloud storage java library in scala to list items in a bucket

```
val credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
  .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
  .setServiceAccountId("xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
  .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_ONLY))
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("file.p12"))
  .build()
val storage = new Storage.Builder(
  GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
  JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
  credential)
  .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
  .setApplicationName("app")
  .build()
storage.objects.list("bucket").execute
```

however I got

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
```

my email account have the access to the bucket, I can access it using gsutil by creating a project in my account as well.
I've created xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com in a project in my account as well, any idea that how can I set the permission?

Answer (score 3):

Just been coming up against the same issue, and think we've found the solution.  To fix it, the owner of the Google Play Developer Console that we were trying to access had to add our service account email address to the Google Play Console permissions list, and give the service account Financial Reports privileges.

Comment: This solution is insecure! Anyone could reverse engineer the APK and get your P12 key. Your Google Could Storage account could be compromised. Here is the unanswered Question I posed, since I am looking for a solution too! http://stackoverflow.com/q/28001476/3216207

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this from a Google Compute Engine instance, make sure you start up that instance with permissions enabled for service accounts... see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using

If you don't start the instance up with a service account, it won't have permissions to use one.