# Able to access bucket in gcloud and Python API but not Java API

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a project that is includes a process to store files into Google Cloud Storage.

The initial prototype was in Python and works fine, however when porting the codebase over to Java I am unable to access the bucket.

The Java project is built with Gradle and development is through NetBeans. The ServiceAccount is a keyfile with restricted access, only allowing for read/write behavior from this particular bucket.

```
// The Java code, which should be enough to grab the bucket.
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
Bucket bucket = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME);

// For comparison, the Python setup.
storage_client = storage.Client()
self.bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
```

When manually running the project from Gradle the result is,

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 
Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to xxx.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to xxx."
}
```

Slightly different when running from within NetBeans itself:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 
Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Anonymous users does not have storage.buckets.get access to a1s-submissions.",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Anonymous users does not have storage.buckets.get access to a1s-submissions."
}
```

All of these methods are returning the expected results
So I know at least the file is being read.

```
StorageOptions.getAppEngineAppId());
StorageOptions.getDefaultProjectId());
StorageOptions.CREDENTIAL_ENV_NAME);GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getApplicationName());
StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getProjectId());
StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getCredentials()
    .getAuthenticationType());
StorageOptions.getLibraryName());
```

So given that I can access the bucket via gcloud and python, I know the account has authorization, however I cannot seem to uncover the cause for this error.

Comment: Similar post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25768735/access-google-cloud-storage-using-java-library-gets-403-forbidden with no answer.

Comment: content you are trying to get is private or public content? If it is private content then you need to create signed URL of the resource before trying to get it.

Comment: Private content. Haven't heard of a signed URL before... why would the Python lib not require this? Thanks for the lead though, was out of ideas. However when using stored key files, the libraries are supposed to only require a filepath to the credentials. Otherwise I would the examples to have a signed URL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, the solution here was in fact to relax the permissions on the service account. I didn't have access to this at the time but was finally able to check this today.

For whatever reason still unknown to me, Python was able to carry out the same operations with the original service account authorization settings while Java required additional rights granted.